# How do I evaluate a limit of a fractional exponent

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I may be going the wrong path for solving this problem, but I don't have the solutions for the exercises I am using so I have no way of checking my work but the  question is to show that $17 n^{1/6} < n^{1/5}$ and to do so I wanted to take the limit as $n \to \infty$. but I was unsure how this works with fractional exponents since taking the derivative will just make a negative exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
\frac{n^{1/5}}{n^{1/6}} = n^{1/5-1/6} = n^{1/30}
$$
and no derivatives are needed.

Comment: in this case, what would this tell me about the limit?